# What is the proper way to add an icon to a tab to a TabHost for Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I'm new to Android development.

I've added a TabHost to my Android application, and can change the text of the three tabs I have just fine. I can click them to show different views, etc.

But where and how do I add an icon to a specific tab? Not change it programmatically, but actually add it on layout design? In the XML or using the designer somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Do as below:

```
    TabHost tabHost=getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabHost.newTabSpec("hello").setIndicator("hello",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

this is easiest way to to set icon to secific tab.

Comment: Is there a way to do it NOT programmatically, so I can see what it looks like in the Android layout designer in Eclipse?

Comment: You will definately see icon on the particular tab by doing this.